# How to get records where given values are within a list of keys

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

## The Problem Statement

I have a collection whose records may look like this

```
{'keys': ['one', 'two', 'three']}
```

Now I want to retrieve all documents which have one or more matches in 'keys' for a given list of match candidates. How does such a query look like using pymongo?

## Example

A collection

```
[
 {'keys': ['tag1']},
 {'keys': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']},
 {'keys': ['tag3', 'tag4']}
]
```

Now

```
my_query({'keys': ['tag1']})
```

should return the first two documents while

```
my_query({'keys': ['tag3']})
```

should return the second and third document and

```
my_query({'keys': ['tag4']})
```

should return only the third document.

```
my_query({'keys': ['tag2', 'tag3']})
```

should return the second and third document.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the below answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use $in operator.

```
 db.collection.find({"keys" : {"$in" : [ "tag1", "tag3" ]} })
```